# How to put delay to submenu when pointer is out? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation with submenu using a list.

```
<nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu">
     <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu-main-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-has-children >
             <a href="#">Books</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li>
                     <div class="megamenu-container container">
                         <div class="row">
                             <li><a href="#">Rental</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
                         </div<
                     </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

When I hover to Books Menu, the **submenu appears**. The submenu is 30 pixels away from the navigation.

The **submenu disappears** when I release my mouse pointer from the Books menu.

Desired result: How to put a **delay on the shown submenu** so that it won't disappear quickly?

Please let me know. 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide the demo for this https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: and what about your css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your html (close the class correctly):

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-has-children">
```

After that my proposal is (the fasein/fadeout take one argument in this case: the delay as you asked):

```js
$(function () {
  $('.sub-menu').hide();
  $('a:contains("Books")').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('.sub-menu').fadeIn(1000)
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    $('.sub-menu').fadeOut(1000)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu-main-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-has-children">
             <a href="#">Books</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <div class="megamenu-container container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <li><a href="#">Rental</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're using jQuery's mouse events because of your title:

```
var leaving;
$('.menu-item-has-children').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').show();
});
$('.menu-item-has-children').mouseleave(function(){
    var $ul = $(this).find('.sub-menu');
    if(leaving){ 
        leaving = clearTimeout(leaving); 
    }
    leaving = setTimeout(function(){
        $ul.hide();
        leaving = undefined;
    }, 500);
});
```

This will handle multiple enter/leave events if done in succession.